# Scaling and Rounding

Tags: optimal-scaling

```
  x     y
 0.4    0
 11.43  11
  0.45  0
  0.44  0
```

Total 12.72 11

I have a very large dataset of x values and rounded off values of x as y. Y cannot take decimals. The totals of x and y are misaligned because of the decimal loss. To address that, I do a linear scaling (multiply y values with 12.72/11) but given that y has to be an integer, rounding off the result will continue to make the y misaligned with x total. Is there a way to make y add up to x while preserving it as an integer?

Comment: maybe do it the other way aroud ? re-scale x by multiplying it with 11/12.72 ?

Comment: There are many solutions to this problem.  It would help therefore to have more information about the purpose of rounding and your intended use of the $y$ values.